# Jquery detect event no active

Tags: jquery, mouseover

**I have this script :**

```
jQuery('#cp_panel_front_into_noticias').mouseover(function() {    
   jQuery(this).jScrollPane({
    showArrows: true,
    arrowScrollOnHover: true
   });
});
```

How you can see if i put mouseover perfectly works , but the question , it´s possible detect the event and when no execute the event mouseover , exists some way for do this ? and no put more code only detect the event ?

Comment: sorry, the question is not clear

Comment: Thank´s i edit but hungerpain more fast as me hehe